# java: how to add values to properties file and access them in program

Tags: java

In my eclipse project i have ip address string variable in many java class files, few jsps and also in context.xml file. I want to create a kind .properties file and declare this ip address as key value pair and access from all the classes from this particular file.How do i achieve this?

Regards
TT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`java.util.Properties.store(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29) to save
- `java.util.Properties.load(..)` to load

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
// Read properties file.
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
    properties.load(new FileInputStream("filename.properties"));
    String value = properties.getProperty("propertyKey");
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Of course, `Properties` is part of java.util.* in your Java SDK, and `"filename.properties"` is supposed to be in your classpath (or alternately, give the full path to the file). In your case, `propertyKey` would be `ipAddress` and the value returned would the configured IP Address